# FB Graph API: Searching Places?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a directory listing of all restaurants located in London, which can be accessed easily via the following URL:

https://www.facebook.com/search/106078429431815/places-in/137670789632630/places/intersect/

However, when I search via the Graph API, I can only search by phrase, eg "Restaurant", which only returns listings that contain that phrase "restaurant".

How can I get the Graph API form of the above link?

Comment: You can't. The search on Facebook.com and the search in the API are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this reference.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search

The main location has to be defined using lat & lang value.
For your case, you have to get the lat & lang value of London.

Here is a sample query to list restaurants in New York.

```
/search?type=place&center=40.7304,-73.9921&distance=1000&categories=["FOOD_BEVERAGE"]&fields=name,about,single_line_address
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from the Graph API main entry point

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/
```

You could query the following endpoint

```
search?access_token=YOURTOKEN&pretty=1&q=club&type=place&limit=25
```

where `q` and `type` are the query parameters you may be interested in.